# PHP SQL Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone please tell me why my function is not working?

```
function myappsbdo($sqlquery, $tabname)
{
try
    {
        $pdo = new       PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=myapps","root","");
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Problème de connexion";
        exit();
    }
$sql = $sqlquery;
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        $tabname  = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
```

I do a var_dump of the variable I chose for my $tabname and it's an empty array. There is suppose to have my db data in it...
Thanks!

EDIT: this is how I call it.
myappsbdo("SELECT * FROM categorie", $tab1);

Comment: What is the value of $tab1 when you call it? Seems like it is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function argument `$tabname` was passed by value, therefore your subsequent assignment to that variable changes only the value of the function-scoped variable `$tabname` and not of the calling-scoped variable `$tab1`.

You want to [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead:

```
function myappsbdo($sqlquery, &$tabname) {
  //                          ^---- notice the ampersand character
  // etc.
  $tabname = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
```

Or, alternatively, return the resultset:

```
function myappsbdo($sqlquery) {
  // etc.
  return $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}

$tab1 = myappsbdp('SELECT * FROM categorie');
```

Note that you probably ought to make your PDO object static, so that the database connection can be reused in successive function calls.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to return the value haha.